# I don't understand my memory error in reference counting

Tags: c++, valgrind, reference-counting

I am implementing a contrived example to follow [this tutorial](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/043.htm) on reference counting:

```
struct Bar
{
    Bar () : refs(1) {}
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    unsigned refs;
};

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo () 
        {
            bar = new Bar;
            bar->x = 5;
            bar->y = 10; 
            bar->z = 15;
        }

        Foo (const Foo &other) : bar(other.bar)
        {
            ++bar->refs;
        }

        Foo& operator = (const Foo &other)
        {
            if (&other != this)
            {
                if (--bar->refs < 1)
                    delete bar;
                bar = other.bar;
                // this would fix it: ++bar->refs;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        ~Foo ()
        {
            if (--bar->refs < 1)
                delete bar;
        }

    private:
        Bar *bar;
};

int main(void)
{
    Foo a;
    Foo b = a;
    Foo c;
    c = b;
}
```

Valgrind gives me the following error, although no memory was leaked.  Could someone help me interpret it?

```
==6814== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==6814== 
==6814== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:
==6814== Invalid read of size 4
==6814==    at 0x400914: Foo::~Foo() (ref-count.cpp:41)
==6814==    by 0x4007CA: main (ref-count.cpp:54)
==6814==  Address 0x4c2d04c is 12 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==6814==    at 0x4A07991: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6814==    by 0x40092E: Foo::~Foo() (ref-count.cpp:42)
==6814==    by 0x4007BE: main (ref-count.cpp:52)
==6814== 
==6814== 
==6814== 1 errors in context 2 of 3:
==6814== Invalid write of size 4
==6814==    at 0x400911: Foo::~Foo() (ref-count.cpp:41)
==6814==    by 0x4007CA: main (ref-count.cpp:54)
==6814==  Address 0x4c2d04c is 12 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==6814==    at 0x4A07991: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6814==    by 0x40092E: Foo::~Foo() (ref-count.cpp:42)
==6814==    by 0x4007BE: main (ref-count.cpp:52)
==6814== 
==6814== 
==6814== 1 errors in context 3 of 3:
==6814== Invalid read of size 4
==6814==    at 0x40090B: Foo::~Foo() (ref-count.cpp:41)
==6814==    by 0x4007CA: main (ref-count.cpp:54)
==6814==  Address 0x4c2d04c is 12 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==6814==    at 0x4A07991: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6814==    by 0x40092E: Foo::~Foo() (ref-count.cpp:42)
==6814==    by 0x4007BE: main (ref-count.cpp:52)
```

**EDIT**: see the commented line in the operator = for the fix.

Comment: You could use std::shared_ptr, which implements reference counting for easy safe resource sharing

Comment: @Manu343726: understanding how a reference counter scheme works is important, and for understanding writing a simple implementation is a thousand times better than just reading about it. Using something non-trivial without understanding how it works is a recipe for a disaster, especially in a complex language like C++ where abstraction leaks are huge.

Comment: This is an isolated part of a larger homework assignment, but most includes are off limits so that we can make our own implementations.

Comment: @6502 of course implementing something is many times better than reading about it. I was just suggesting OP to use a working, standard, and tested alternative. Of course if it's goal is to learn about reference counting, I encourage her/him to finish the implementation and test it deeply.

Answer (score 4):

The copy-assignment operator needs to increment the reference count.

Comment: Yep, that was it; easy fix.  Perhaps it's time to take a break now.